# Accurate test count when using decorators to supply unit-test data

Tags: python, unit-testing, decorator

I use a function decorator to feed data via data-provider-functions to my python unit tests. My solutions is pretty similar to what [this guy does](http://melp.nl/2011/02/phpunit-style-dataprovider-in-python-unit-test/). Everything works fine with one minor, but quite annoying exception:

In phpUnit, when using a data provider, the test count goes up with each data set that is provided. When I add a data-set and the test passes, I can easily see that the new data set was run, since my test count goes up. In python, using a decorator, the test count stays the same. What I have been doing so far to make sure that data sets are run when tests pass from the get go is introduce errors on purpose, to see the test fail. This is not the end of the world, but it is annoying enough that I felt like asking for help here.

Is there a way to increase the test count for each data set provided via decorator?

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet shows how a counter can be used within a decorator.
I hope you can transfer that to your code.

```
def log(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print('{} {} {} {}'.format(str(inner.count), str(func), args, kwargs))
        inner.count += 1
        return func(args, kwargs)
    inner.count = 1
    return inner


@log
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print('{}{}'.format(args, kwargs))


def main():
    foo(1, 2, 3, 4)
    foo('a')
    foo('asdf', 'asdf')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This example will print:

```
1 <function foo at 0x2711848> (1, 2, 3, 4) {}
((1, 2, 3, 4), {}){}
2 <function foo at 0x2711848> ('a',) {}
(('a',), {}){}
3 <function foo at 0x2711848> ('asdf', 'asdf') {}
(('asdf', 'asdf'), {}){}
```

This is one way to increase the test count for each data set provided via decorator.

Comment: If it turns out that having each data set register as a unique test is impossible, this would be a great workaround!